# Cumulative count per year in SQL

Tags: sql, count, mariadb

I have an "activity" table, a "customer" table and a "customer_activity" table. In the "activity" table each activity has its own id and a Start, End year:
Thus, each row represents an activity, the first column is the start year and the second column the End year (Say that, the following are the activities of a specific customer with name X1).

```
    Start   End    Act_ID
    2007    2008    1
    2007    2008    2
    2009    2009    3
    2008    2008    4
    2008    2011    5
    2007    2008    6
    2007    2008    7
    2006    2007    8
    2006    2006    9
    2011    2013    10
    2011    2013    11
```

The table "customer" has customer ID and customer name. Finally
the table "customer_activity" has customer ID and activity ID.
I want query by customer name (say customer with name X1) and get a table like this:

```
        Year  New   Total
        2006   2      2
        2007   4      5  
        2008   1      4
        2009   1      2
        2010   0      1
        2011   2      3
        2012   0      2
        2013   0      2
```

I use mariadb 10.1.10. 
Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: You have shot yourself in the foot with that activity table. It would be better to set it up with ID, date. Then, it would be simple to say `select year (date), sum (id) from tablename group by year (date)`. As it is, you will probably have to use a procedure to fill in the missing dates.

Comment: Some algorithms are best done in application code, not SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having replaced your relevant column names, you could try this:

```
select a.start, count(*) as total, count(c.id) as new
from (select distinct(start) from activity) a 
       left join activity b 
       on a.start between b.start and b.end 
       left join activity c
       on b.id=c.id and a.start=c.start
where b.id in (select customer_activity.id
            from customer left join customer_activity
            on customer.id = customer_activity.customer_id
            where customer.name = "X1" ) 
group by a.start
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of years, you can use `join` and aggregation:

```
select y.yyyy,
       sum(case when y.yyyy = ca.start then 1 else 0 end) as news,
       count(ca.customer_id) as total
from (select 2007 as yyyy union all select 2008 union all . . .
      select 2013
     ) y left join
     customer_activity ca
     on y.yyyy between ca.start and ca.end left join
     customer c
     on ca.customer_id = c.customer_id and c.name = 'X1'
group by y.yyyy
order by y.yyyy;
```

The best way to generate such the list of years depends on the database.

Comment: I wouldn't like to manually enter the years: 'select 2007 as yyyy union all...' 
is there a way to do that automatically?

Comment: I also don't get how you join y with customer_activity on start and end year. customer_activity doesn't have any year columns.
Am I missing something?